# UISearchDisplayController - I want a grouped table

Tags: ipad, uitableview, xcode4, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I added a UISearchDisplayController using the interface builder in XCode 4.2, and it added a UITableView automatically.

The problem is that i want it to be grouped table, but i couldn't find how to change it.
Got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can't change it.

If you want to use a grouped table, forgo the `UISearchDisplayController` and use a combination of `UISearchBar` and new `UITableView` instance. You can create this table view programmatically or using `Interface Builder`.

Either ways attach it to a `searchTableView` property and keep it off the view hierarchy. When the search begins, attach it to the view hierarchy and lay it over the original table view.

This will involve a good deal of additional work but if you want it a grouped search table, this is the way to go.